# How can I compile 32- and 64-bit DCUs into separate directories?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to maintain one repository, most everything in my code base is source, but we've got the QuickPDF library which is a bunch of precompiled DCU's.  I'd like to put them in version control somehow but I don't want to have yet another option set for win64 that I'm going to forget about before I convert the rest of my trillion LOC codebase to win64.

What I was thinking was just having (and quickPDF is just an example, there's nothing special about this library other than its unfortunate precompiledness)

- ctrls\quickpdf\QuickPDF.pas
- ctrls\quickpdf\win32[*.dcu]
- ctrls\quickpdf\win64[*.dcu]

From the looks of the folders in Program Files, Embarcadero does something similar with the VCL. There are even some precompiled things there, like VCL.Imaging.JPEG.pas.

How do I do the same thing? Do I need to specify win32 and win64 folders, or is there some magic somewhere I can tap in to?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Do you want a macro that will expand so your library path will automagically redirect to a _32 or _64 suffix? Because I think you just set up the 32 bit library path and a 64 bit library path separately, right? And you're done.

Comment: @Warren P, thanks, somehow that comment got me thinking and I actually looked at the library paths for the VCL under Tools->Options. Got an answer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The magic you are talking about can be seen in the .dproj file for a plain vanilla XE2 VCL Forms app. The key ingredients are these variables:

- `$(Platform)` which can be Win32 or Win64 on Windows.
- `$(Config)` which is commonly either Debug or Release.

Then in the .dproj file the following XML performs the magic:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
    <DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
    <DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can use such tricks with the `$(Platform)` and `$(Config)` variables with any of the project options. So you just need to use these variables to set whatever option needs to be set for the compiler to find your pre-compiled DCUs.

To the best of my knowledge the option you need to set is the Search Path. Although I admit to being hazy about how the search path works since I personally never rely on search path and always explicitly include all source files in my projects. In your example you would add `ctrls\quickpdf\($Platform)` to the search path.

Comment: Just a want to point out that even though it shows up as grayed out in the IDE it still works (kind of annoying when hitting 'delete invalid paths')

Comment: @Peter It's greyed out because you need to select the base configuration (All configurations in a vanilla project) in order to edit it.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it in the base configuration.  check out my post below - I just added a picture.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're talking about, the problem is A.) these are precompiled DCU files (I don't have the source for them, I'm not happy about that but, oh well) and B.) Do you actually put the unit output directory in version control?  We're new to using SVN for our project (VSS holdouts), I just changed the DCU folder to be a relative path so until recently I'd have never even considered this.

Comment: You want put unit output directory under revision control. I'm not sure which setting controls where the compiler looks for pre-compiled DCUs. I don't use pre-compiled DCUs. The main point of the answer is the existence of these special variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the compiler does not have a different setting for where to look for precompiled dcu's. It's just that with precompiled dcu's it can never find the source or finds the dcu "earlier" in the search path than the source.

Comment: @marjan so the solution in this case is to use the search path and the $(Platform) variable?

Comment: @david: yep that should do it. And I agree that the output dir (and the exe dir) should be under source control. We have relative paths for them and each project in our 53+ suite has its own dcu folder. This way compiler/conditional defines for one project never mess up the dcu's for another. And allowing for the 32/64 "split" was "a breeze" (we just had to add a lot of "EnsureFolder.txt" files to our repository so all these dcu folders are guaranteed to be present in our build server.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple, add:

- ..\ctrls\quickpdf\$(Platform)

to your projects search path

Although you'll be surprised when you find this actually works since it shows up grayed out in the IDE.

[image: Project Options - Search Path]

Comment: Note: Usually the "Unit output directory" (as shown in David Heffernan's answer) is considered part of the search path (as a default). Unlike this solution, you don't have the annoying issue of the path being grayed-out.